# Problem running Lazarus project on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: lazarus, pascal

I recently installed Lazarus IDE on my Ubuntu 12.04 via Software Center, later I tried it via commands in console. Both were effective, program was successfully installed but I was unable to run my projects (the program was able to compile the code but there was no window with result of code).

After clicking Run, it shows me a message box with name `Invalid launching app` and the following text:

```
Launching application ""/media/Windows/Lazarus/19.2/project1"" doesn't exist or is unable to launch.
look Launch -> Parameters of launch -> Local
```

So I checked the setting, in local I allow the launching app. When i run it again it just showed me this text in terminal:

```
/media/Windows/Lazarus/19.2/project1
  /usr/lib/lazarus/0.9.30.2//tools/runwait.sh: 16:
  /usr/lib/lazarus/0.9.30.2//tools/runwait.sh: /media/Windows/Lazarus/19.2/project1:
  Permission denied -----------
```

Note: Windows is just the partition name on my hardisk.

Answer (score 0):

You question is too broad but let me see if I can address it correctly.

1. First you've not mentioned if you're running a console application or a Lazarus GUI project.
2. From what I see, you seem to have a dual boot system or a hard disk with a Windows partition, apart from Ubuntu.

Now here are some tips:

1. If you don't see the 'result' of a console program in Lazarus, that's normal. The compile program runs so quickly and returns to the IDE. So what you need to do is hold it in that output screen by (for example) putting a Readln statement before your program ends.
2. If you're trying to run a GUI program, perhaps your code is ending because of a button or other component has an event to exit on focus. On Ubuntu (perhaps this is a bug) I noticed that 'on focus' triggers the click event as well. This issue is non existent on Windows.
3. If you have a project on the Windows partition, Lazarus (by default) cannot correctly execute it. I had the same issue but I decided to keep the development project in the Ubuntu partition itself.
4. When you say your project doesn't run from the terminal, I assume you run it by typing the program name in the console. By default, Ubuntu doesn't allow this to be done by simply using the program name. You have to use the following method:

   ./PROGRAM-NAME

I hope this helps.